# Allow users to send email to email address stored in model using Contact Form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, contact-form

I have a directory website. Each "Directory" is a listing. Each listing model has an email attribute.

How can I have my users send an email to the "listing owner"?

My thought thus far was to use the ContactForm Gem and add an :email attribute to my Listing model. Then use ContactForm Gem and put a form in each show page. However my approach is not working. Any thoughts on how to have ContactForm Model accept the @listing.email attribute?

If not what is another way to get this done?
Thanks for your help in advance!

My controller looks as follows:

**Controller:**

```
class ContactFormsController < ApplicationController

 def new
  @listing = Listing.params[:id]
  @contact_form = ContactForm.new
 end

def create
  begin @contact_form = ContactForm.new(params[:contact_form]) 
    @contact_form.request = request 
      if @contact_form.deliver
          flash.now[:notice] = 'Thank you for your interest!'
          redirect_to root_path
        else
          render :new
        end
      rescue ScriptError
        flash[:error] = 'Sorry, something was wrong'
      end
   end
end
```

**Model:**

```
class ContactForm < MailForm::Base
attribute :name,      :validate => true
attribute :email,     :validate => /\A([\w\.%\+\-]+)@([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,})\z/i
attribute :file,      :attachment => true

attribute :message
attribute :nickname,  :captcha  => true

# Declare the e-mail headers. It accepts anything the mail method
# in ActionMailer accepts.
def headers
{
  :subject => "My Contact Form",
  :to => "#{@listing.email}",
  :from => %("#{name}" <#{email}>)
}
end
end
```

Comment: Solve the problem ? If not you read the Gem documentation about that ? Have the link to show us ?

Comment: No I didn't. Here is the link to the Gem docs: [link](https://github.com/plataformatec/mail_form) Maybe I am using the wrong Gem and should just use ActionMailer? I'm not sure.